# How to obtain the path of a Bash script, when it’s executed through a symlink?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, macos

I want to obtain the path of a Bash script, is when it’s executed through a symlink.

In this case, `$0` is `-bash`, while `BASH_SOURCE` is the symlink’s path.

Can I obtain the script’s path through some shell variable, built-in shell command, or external command?

Will `BASH_SOURCE` always holds the initial symlink’s path, even if the script is executed through several levels of indirection (multiple symlinks)?

Could I use `ls` with `BASH_SOURCE` to always retrieve the script’s path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`realpath` or `readlink -f` from GNU coreutils might help:

```
$ ls -l foo.sh bar.sh whereami.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu  6 Jul 31 19:01 bar.sh -> foo.sh*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 11 Jul 31 19:01 foo.sh -> whereami.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 36 Jul 31 19:02 whereami.sh*
$ cat whereami.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$BASH_SOURCE"
realpath "$BASH_SOURCE"
$ ./bar.sh
./bar.sh
/tmp/whereami.sh
```